# I want to delete only the voice channels in one category

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Here is my code:

```py
import discord, asyncio
    
app = discord.Client()
    
@app.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    username = str(member)
    guild = app.get_guild(660213767820410893)
    ch = guild.get_channel(660213767820410918)
    category = guild.get_channel(660213767820410908)
    
    if after.channel == ch:
        channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(
                name=username+"`s Room",
                category=category,
                user_limit=99
            )
        await member.move_to(channel)
        await channel.set_permissions(member, manage_channels=True)
    if not before.channel.members and before.channel != ch:
        await before.channel.delete()
```

I want to delete only the voice channels in one category. For now, all channels are deleted.

Comment: You should check if the channel category matches said category

Comment: Matches MatchesMatches

Comment: Please check my answer below. If it helped, don't forget to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only want to delete the [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicechannel) if it's in the [`category`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#categorychannel) ? If yes, you could just add the condition: `before.channel.category == category` in the last `if` block:

```py
import discord, asyncio
    
app = discord.Client()
    
@app.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    username = str(member)
    guild = app.get_guild(660213767820410893)
    ch = guild.get_channel(660213767820410918)
    category = guild.get_channel(660213767820410908)
    
    if after.channel == ch:
        channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(
                name=username+"`s Room",
                category=category,
                user_limit=99
            )
        await member.move_to(channel)
        await channel.set_permissions(member, manage_channels=True)

    b_channel = before.channel
    if b_channel: # If the user was connected to a voice channel before 
        if not b_channel.members and b_channel != ch and b_channel.category == category:
            await b_channel.delete()
```